# Load a bulk of local images (106X2) into 2 UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, ios4, uiscrollview

I have 2 scroll views, and I need to load 106 Images into every scroll view, below is the code I'm using, but it crashes when I'm trying to test it on my iphone 4.

Every image is around 30-40KB, so the size is not the reason.

If you have any idea, I'll be very thankful!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

Images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Slogans = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i =1; i<=106; i++) {
        int r = i-1;
        [self.Images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%da.jpg",i]]];
        [self.Slogans addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",i]]];
        NSLog(@"%d.jpg",i );
        NSLog(@"%da.jpg",i );

        NSLog(@"Images count: %d",self.Images.count);
         NSLog(@"Slogans count: %d",self.Slogans.count);

        //Images
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.ImagesScrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.ImagesScrollView.frame.size;
        UIImageView *ImagesSubview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        ImagesSubview.image = [self.Images objectAtIndex:r];
        [self.ImagesScrollView addSubview:ImagesSubview];
        [ImagesSubview release];


        //Slogans
        CGRect Sframe;
        Sframe.origin.x = self.SlogansScrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        Sframe.origin.y = 0;
        Sframe.size = self.SlogansScrollView.frame.size;
        UIImageView *SlogansSubview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:Sframe];

        SlogansSubview.image = [self.Slogans objectAtIndex:r];
        [self.SlogansScrollView addSubview:SlogansSubview];
        [SlogansSubview release];
 }

    [SpageControl setNumberOfPages:Images.count];
    [pageControl setNumberOfPages:Images.count];




    self.ImagesScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.ImagesScrollView.frame.size.width * Images.count, self.ImagesScrollView.frame.size.height);

     self.SlogansScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.SlogansScrollView.frame.size.width * Slogans.count, self.SlogansScrollView.frame.size.height);


}
```

Comment: And what does the crash report say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30-40 kb filesize indicates nothing about the actual memory needed to hold those images.

You would be better off using a UITableView and dynamically loading the images as needed OR using one of the UIScrollView examples from Apple: [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and [ScrollViewSutie](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) which demo tiling.